# Captcha integration issues to contact form

Tags: php, forms, contacts, captcha, contact-form

I want to use captcha in the contact section of my website to get rid of spam messages. When I add the captcha codes I found to the contact form, the message is sent, but the captcha does not work. If I close the action section of the contact form, the captcha works and the mail does not go. If I open the action line of the contact form, this time it conflicts with the action of the captcha code and the captcha does not work.

contact.php form codes

```
<article id="content" style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;">
  <header class="module-a" style="padding-left: 10px;">
    <h2>Contact Information</h2>
  </header>
  
</article>
<article id="content" class="cols-b">
  <form  onSubmit="return submitForm();" action="contact-mail-action.php" method="post" class="form-b" name="homefrm1" id="homefrm1">
  <input type="hidden"  name="event" value="start" />
  <fieldset>
  <div class="container">
  <legend>Send us a message</legend>
  <form method="POST" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="adsoyad">Name-Surname</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="adsoyad" id="adsoyad" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="konu">Subject</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="konu" id="konu" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="mesaj">Message</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="mesaj" id="mesaj" rows="3" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="islem" value="gonder" required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <aside>
    <h3>Location</h3>
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m17!1m12!1m3!1d658.4309168065989!2d32.00941005065839!3d36.54806161318423!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m2!1m1!2zMzbCsDMyJzUzLjYiTiAzMsKwMDAnMzUuOSJF!5e0!3m2!1str!2str!4v1699341329906!5m2!1str!2str" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
  </aside>
</article>
```

captcha.php codes

```
<?PHP

$image = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 30) or die("hata oluştu");

// arkaplan rengi oluşturuyoruz
$background = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $background);
$linecolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33);

// rast gele çizgiler oluşturuyoruz
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    imagesetthickness($image, rand(1, 3));
    imageline($image, 0, rand(0, 30), 120, rand(0, 30), $linecolor);
}

session_start();

// rastgele sayılar oluşturuyoruz
$sayilar = '';
for ($x = 15; $x <= 95; $x += 20) {
    $sayilar .= ($sayi = rand(0, 9));
    imagechar($image, rand(3, 5), $x, rand(2, 14), $sayi, $textcolor);
}

// sayıları session aktarıyoruz
$_SESSION['
captcha
'] = $sayilar;

// resim gösteriliyor ve sonrasında siliniyor
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Captcha control.php codes

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CAPTCHA</title>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<br>

<strong>
    Robot olmadığınızı kanıtlamak için görseldeki metni yazın
</strong>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <div style='margin:15px'>
        <img src="captcha.php" id="capt">
        <input type=button onClick=reload(); value='Tekrar Yükle'>
    </div>


    <input type="text" name="deger"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Giriş" name="submit"/>
</form>

<div style='margin-top:5px'>
    <?php

    session_start();
    // Kullanıcı bir captcha verdiyse!
    if (isset($_POST['deger']))

        // Captcha geçerliyse
        if ($_POST['deger'] == $_SESSION['captcha'])
            echo '<span style="color:green">BAŞARILI</span>';
        else
            echo '<span style="color:red">
CAPTCHA 
BAŞARISIZ!!!</span>';
    ?>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function reload() {
        img = document.getElementById("capt");
        img.src = "captcha.php"
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"If I close the action section of the contact form"_ - not sure what that is supposed to mean. You appear to have nested one form into another in your first code snippet there, which is not allowed in HTML. You need to combine all of this into _one_ form.